# Is it possible to use a data.enter() method within a data.enter() method?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I think the title is self-explanatory.

Lets say I'm entering some divs like this and using each to create a separate enter cascade:

```
var rects = g.selectAll("rect").data(data);

  rects.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width","100px")
    .attr("height","100px")
    .attr("y",function(d,i){ return margin.top + (i * spacing) + "px"})
    .attr("x",margin.left + "px")
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return "d.color" }
    .each(function(d,i){
      var that = d3.select(this)
         that.selectAll('circle.timelinefeatures')
           .data(allevents)
           .enter()
             .append('circle')
              .attr('class',"timelinecircles")
            });
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Sounds like you want [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).

Answer (score 3):

I think this example from d3's API reference for [`selection.data(values, key)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data) illustrates the point well:

> The *values* array specifies the data for each group in the selection. Thus, if the selection has multiple groups (such as a [d3.selectAll](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_selectAll) followed by a [selection.selectAll](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#selectAll)), then data should be specified as a function that returns an array (assuming that you want different data for each group). The function will be passed the current group data (or `undefined`) and the index, with the group as the `this` context. For example, you may bind a two-dimensional array to an initial selection, and then bind the contained inner arrays to each subselection. The values function in this case is the identity function: it is invoked for each group of child elements, being passed the data bound to the parent element, and returns this array of data.

```
var matrix = [
  [11975,  5871, 8916, 2868],
  [ 1951, 10048, 2060, 6171],
  [ 8010, 16145, 8090, 8045],
  [ 1013,   990,  940, 6907]
];

var tr = d3.select("body").append("table").selectAll("tr")
    .data(matrix)
  .enter().append("tr");

var td = tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter().append("td")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

See also: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#selectAll

```
var rects = g.selectAll("rect").data(data);
rects.enter().append("rect");

var tf = rects.selectAll('circle.timelinefeatures').data(function(d, i) {
    return d;
});
tf.enter().append('circle').attr('class', 'timelinefeatures');
```

Comment: So this has one problem. If your original data array has subarrays, only the first subarray will be appended in the second selection.

Comment: Would you care to edit your post to include your data's structure?